# event priority in shopware 5

Tags: php, events, shopware, shopware5

i have 2 plugins both use same event `Enlight_Controller_Action_PostDispatchSecure_Frontend_Checkout`
in plugin A i assing a variable to smarty and need that variable for my other plugin.
but plugin B runs before plugin A. so i set priorities and tested it with a var_dump();
Plugin A:

```
 public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [
        'Enlight_Controller_Action_PostDispatchSecure_Frontend_Checkout' => array('onCheckout', 1)
    ];
}
public function onPostDispatchCheckout(\Enlight_Event_EventArgs $args)
    {
        var_dump("Plugin A");
    }
```

Plugin B:

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [
        'Enlight_Controller_Action_PostDispatchSecure_Frontend_Checkout' => array('onCheckout', 2)
    ];
}
    public function onPostDispatchCheckout(\Enlight_Event_EventArgs $args)
    {
        var_dump("Plugin B");
    }
```

now when I run it, the output is:

```
plugin B, Plugin A
```

but plugin A must run first, what am I doing wrong ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The higher the number, the earlier a subscriber is executed. So you have to change the priorities.

Plugin A:

```php
 public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [
        'Enlight_Controller_Action_PostDispatchSecure_Frontend_Checkout' => array('onCheckout', 2)
    ];
}
public function onPostDispatchCheckout(\Enlight_Event_EventArgs $args)
    {
        var_dump("Plugin A");
    }
```

Plugin B:

```php
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [
        'Enlight_Controller_Action_PostDispatchSecure_Frontend_Checkout' => array('onCheckout', 1)
    ];
}
    public function onPostDispatchCheckout(\Enlight_Event_EventArgs $args)
    {
        var_dump("Plugin B");
    }
```

Comment: i tried that aswell it didnt work :(

Comment: did you cleared the cache completely after you changed it? especially the generated Symfony container needs to be re-created anew

Answer (score 2):

As Pawel mentioned you can set the priority in the event subscription. There are two syntaxes to do this

event => [subscriber => priority]

'Enlight_Controller_Action_PostDispatchSecure_Frontend_Checkout' => ['onCheckout' => 1]

or

event => [subscriber, priority]

'Enlight_Controller_Action_PostDispatchSecure_Frontend_Checkout' => ['onCheckout', 1]

As far as I know its like z-index, the higher one wins. And you might need to reinstall the plugin and clear the cache.

Comment: ive tried again using a different plugin, still doesnt work unfortunately, even cleared cache and all that but still didint work.

Comment: did you tried switching priorities? plugin b with priority 2 and plugin a with 1?

Comment: yes i did, i even reinstalled both plugins and put die("1") and die("2") and always die 1 came first even tho the other priority was higher